# Prevent animation on every row

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on this code example of collapsible text.

[jsfiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/wkvcyyxj/1/)

HTML:

```
<div class="container faq_wrapper">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span10 offset1">
            <p>
                &nbsp;</p>
            <div class="faq-all-actions">
                <a class="faq-expand">Expand All</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;<a class="faq-collapse">Collapse All</a></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span10 offset1">
            <div class="question-wrapper">
                <div class="arrows">
                    &nbsp;</div>
                <div class="big-q">
                    Q</div>
                <div class="question">
                    <div class="arrow" ></div><h6><font size="6">Can I try the software before I buy it?</font></h6></div>
                <div class="answer-wrapper">
                    <div class="big-a">
                        A</div>
                    <div class="answer">
                        Yes! Simply <a href="/trial">download a free trial</a> and you&#39;ll have instant access to all features for 30 days, absolutely free. We don&#39;t require your credit card details or any commitment.</div>
                </div>
            </div>    
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="span10 offset1">
            <div class="question-wrapper">
                <div class="arrows">
                    &nbsp;</div>
                <div class="big-q">
                    Q</div>
                <div class="question">
                    <div class="arrow" ></div><h6><font size="6">Can I try the software before I buy it?</font></h6></div>
                <div class="answer-wrapper">
                    <div class="big-a">
                        A</div>
                    <div class="answer">
                        Yes! Simply <a href="/trial">download a free trial</a> and you&#39;ll have instant access to all features for 30 days, absolutely free. We don&#39;t require your credit card details or any commitment.</div>
                </div>
            </div>    
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$(document)
    .on('click','.row .question-wrapper',function(){ 
        $(this).find('.answer-wrapper').slideToggle();
        $('.arrow').toggleClass('down');
    })

    .on('click','.faq-expand',function(){
        $('.answer-wrapper').slideDown();
        $('.arrow').addClass('down');
    })

    .on('click','.faq-collapse',function(){
        $('.answer-wrapper').slideUp();
        $('.arrow').removeClass('down');
    })
```

There is a issue with the code when i expand the first row. When I click on one row arrow animation is activated also on all rows. How I can prevent this?

Comment: Use the same `$(this).find('.answer-wrapper')` in the second and third blocks as you use in your first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you use this:

```
$('.arrow').toggleClass('down');
```

This will toggle the class for *all* elements with arrow class

You want to limit it to the question being clicked on

```
$(this).find(".arrow").toggleClass('down');
//or
$(".arrow",this).toggleClass('down');
```

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wkvcyyxj/2/)